# Convert json string to list and compare with other list

Tags: asp.net-core

I converted the string to a json list and I want to compare the two lists and add only the records that are in the new list and are not in the database.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddRoleAccessActions(string SelectedItems, string RoleName)
    {
        List<AccessActionViewModel> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<AccessActionViewModel>>(SelectedItems);

       var list = _context.RoleAccessAction.Where(a=>a.RoleName == RoleName).ToList();

       var test = items.Except(list).ToList();

        if (items.Count() != 0)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= items.Count() - 1; j++)
            {
                RoleAccessAction roleAccessActions = new RoleAccessAction();

                roleAccessActions.RoleName = RoleName;
                roleAccessActions.AccessActionName = items[j].AccessActionName;
                await _context.RoleAccessAction.AddAsync(roleAccessActions);
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        return Ok(new ReturnModel(new Collection { MessageLib.Message.Create.Successful }, "".ToList(), MessageLib.Message.statusCode.CreateSuccessful));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Except` method uses object reference equality.  Even though some objects may have the same `AccessActionName` they are not the same object.  The first list is created by a Json Deserialization and the second list is created from the database.  Therefore there will be no object reference equality matches.

Best to use Where method:

```
IEnumerable<string> existingAccessActionNames =
    list.Select(l => l.AccessActionName);

var test = items.Where(i => !existingActionNames.Contains(i.AccessActionName));
```

Or, rolled into a single statement:

```
var test = items
    .Where(i => !list.Select(l => l.AccessActionName).Contains(i.AccessActionName));
```